# Recursively perform an operation on all files in a directory and its subdirectories

Tags: bash, find, recursive

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1333837/15603477), I want to perform an operation on all the files in a directory and its subdirectories.

The following command works a single file, and also works when used on multiple files in a loop.

```bash
for i in *.html; \
do sed -i '/<head>/a <link rel="stylesheet" href="/home/jian/postgres/doc/src/sgml/html/stylesheet.css">\' $i; \
done
```

But the following command will not work.

```bash
find . -type d -exec \
    for i in *.html; \
    do sed -i '/<head>/a <link rel="stylesheet" href="/home/jian/postgres/doc/src/sgml/html/stylesheet.css">\' $i; \
    done \
 \;
```

It gives the following error:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
;: command not found
```

I found a related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21479607/15603477).

Comment: Why are you running `find . -type d -exec` if you want to make an operation on html files? Why not `find . -type f -name '*.html'` and then exec the `sed` command directly on those files?

Comment: @aviro can you give a full answer....

Comment: FYI, that  first for loop of yours has an arbitrary command execution vulnerability as you forgot the `--` (need with GNU `find` at least, the one that supports `-i` and can run commands) and the quotes around `$i`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `sed` from `find` for all regular files with names matching `*.html` in the current directory or below:

```bash
find . -name '*.html' -type f -exec sed -i '...expression...' {} +
```

Assuming you correctly insert your `sed` expression in the code above, this will call `sed` with batches pathnames of found files, ensuring that `sed` is invoked as *few* times as possible.

Alternatively,

```bash
shopt -s globstar dotglob failglob

sed -i '...expression...' ./**/*.html
```

This enables the `**` pattern which works like `*` but matches across `/` in pathnames ("recursively").  It also allows patterns to match hidden names (like `find` would also do), and tells the shell to fail with an error if no names matches a pattern.

The difference here is that

1. The filetype of matching files is not tested (the pattern may match directories etc.)
2. If the pattern matches many *thousands* of names, the command will fail to execute with a "Argument list too long" error.

Comment: `sed -i '/<head>/a <link rel="stylesheet" href="/home/jian/postgres/doc/src/sgml/html/stylesheet.css">\' ./**/*.html ` seems not work.  says: `sed: can't read ./**/*.html: No such file or directory
`

Comment: @jian I believe you forgot to also run the `shopt` command that was part of that code. It was not merely decorative :-)